# Problem with Rock Scissor Paper program in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with my program. I want it to execute a loop that makes the result of the game and increments the score. But for some reason it doesn't make the exiting loop or shows the correct score. Below is the code. What the problem could there be.?

Is the there something wrong with the function calls. I want to execute ask the player if he wants to continue and in the case he wants to play to shwo the new score.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


void game_exit(void);
void game_playing(void); 
void game_choice_menu(); 
int algorithm(int *player_choice, int *computer_choice); 

int main()
{
    system("clear"); 

    printf("\n|==============================|\n|     ROCK-SCISSORS-PAPER      |\n|==============================|\n");
    printf("\n1.Start Playing!\n2.Exit!\n\nWhat you wanna do: (pick 1 or 2):    ");
    int input; 
    scanf("%d",&input);

    switch (input)
    {   case 1:
            game_playing(); 
            game_exit();
            break;
        case 2: 
            game_exit();
            break;
        default: 
            printf("WRONG INPUT!! TRY AGAIN!!!");
            game_exit();
            break;
    }

}

void game_choice_menu(void)
{   
    static int player,computer; 
    player =0; 
    computer = 0; 
    system("clear");
    printf("PLAYER : %d COMPUTER: %d \n", player, computer);
    printf("===============================");
    printf("\nRock, Scissors or Paper? (1 for Rock, 2 for Scissors and 3 for Paper) ");
    int answer;
       do{  
    scanf("%d",&answer);} while (answer<=1 && answer>=3);
    int computer_choice = rand()% 3;
    int result;
    result = algorithm(&answer,&computer_choice);
    if (result==0) {
        player++;
        //system("pause 3");
        printf("\n YOU WON!!!\n");}
    else {  
        //system("pause 3");
        printf("\n YOU LOSE!!!\n");
        computer++;}
}

int algorithm(int *player_choice, int *computer_choice)
{


 if ( *player_choice < *computer_choice)
    {
        if ( (*computer_choice - *player_choice)==2)
            return 1;   
        else if ((*computer_choice - *player_choice)==1)
            return 0;   
    }

    else if (*player_choice > *computer_choice)
    {
        if ((*player_choice - *computer_choice)==2)
            return 1; 
        if ((*player_choice - *computer_choice)==1)
            return 0;
    }
}

void game_playing(void)
{
        for (;;) 
    {
        game_choice_menu();
        //printf("\n Want to play again? (Y for yes, N for no)");
        //char reply; 
        //scanf("%c",&reply); 
        //if (reply == 'y' || reply == 'Y')
        //  continue;
        //else if (reply == 'n' || reply == 'N') 
        //  break;



    }   

}

void game_exit(void)
{
    system("clear"); 
    printf("THANK YOU FOR PLAYING!!!");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You have an explicit infinite loop in `game_playing`. Why do you use `for(;;)` there?

Comment: Also, `answer<=1 && answer>=3` can never be true. Perhaps you meant to use `||`.